# Getting additional data from Firebase Auth Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an application with Firebase Web and Javascript.
I built a Facebook Login, but i can't understand how to access the scopeData i requested in the sign-in step.
Here is my signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult code:

```
// signInWithRedirect
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user_birthday');
provider.addScope('user_friends');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

// getRedirectResult
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result){
if(result.credential)
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  var user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error.code);
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: In Facebook developer portal there is a way to request additional/elevated oAuth data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently additional OAuth provider data is not returned in Firebase. You will need to use the access token returned and query facebook api to get that additional information.

Comment: Hi.so meaning these 2 lines are useless?

provider.addScope('user_birthday');
provider.addScope('user_friends');

Comment: They are not useless. The access token returned will provide access to these additional scopes. You would need to query the Facebook API with that access token to get this data (specific to user friends and birthday). By the way, additional user info is now returned specific to IdP. This was launched in May. Check content of `result.additionalUserInfo.profile`.